# What's the correct way to create a dictionary typealias?

Tags: swift, dictionary

If I want to define a `typealias` for a Dictionary, which accept `String` as the key, and `String` for the value, but I also want it to can accept `nil`, which one of these definition is correct?

```
typealias dictString = Dictionary<String, String?>
```

or

```
typealias dictString = Dictionary<String, String>
```

or

```
typealias dictString = [String:String?]
```

or

```
typealias dictString = [String:String]
```

Because I use the first one, and now each time I want to unwrap a value, I need to unwrap it twice (e.g. `dict["name"]!!`) so I began to wondering whether I really need to add the question mark or not (but I need the dictionary to still able to take nil value). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second and fourth are okay.

You don't need to make the value optional in most cases. You can set a key's value to `nil` even if you did not declare the value as an optional type:

```
var dict = [String: String]()
dict["Hello"] = nil
```

And when you access `"Hello"`, it returns `nil`. Fantastic!

In fact, setting a key's value to `nil` means to "delete the key". This can cause unexpected results if you don't know this.

For example,

```
var dict = [String: String]()
dict["Hello"] = nil
print(dict.keys.contains("Hello"))
```

prints `false`.

If you need to check if a key exists even if its value is `nil`, then you have to make the value an optional type.

Comment: Oh okay, I just afraid that somewhere along the way, when I access dict["Hello"] it will raise an error because I was accessing a nil value or something (producing the famous `SIGABRT` error)...

Comment: @ChenLiYong no a dictionary will never do that, unless the dictionary is nil, of course.

Comment: Ooooooh! Okay, now I get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary will return `nil` for any key that's not present. Now, if you want to be able to actually have the key present but have the value nil then version `1` and `3` are the way to go and you keep the double unwrapping. Otherwise use `2` or `4`.

**Update**

**Example:**

Version 1 & 3:

```
typealias DictString = Dictionary<String, String?> // or [String: String?]
var myDict: DictString = ["MyKey1": "MyVal1", "MyKey2": nil]
var value1: String? = myDict["MyKey1"]! // This is an Optional String so you'd need to unwrap it
var value2: String? = myDict["MyKey2"]! // This will return nil
```

Version 2 & 4:

```
typealias DictString = Dictionary<String, String> // or [String: String]
var myDict: DictString = ["MyKey1": "MyVal1"]
var value1: String? = myDict["MyKey1"] // This is an Optional String so you'd need to unwrap it
var value2: String? = myDict["MyKey2"] // This will return nil
```

Now the difference between the two is that the first case actually stores the keys. So if you ever do this:

```
var allKeys: [String] = Array(myDict.keys)
```

You'll get two different results:

- 1 & 3: `allKeys` will be `["MyKey1", "MyKey2"]`
- 2 & 4: `allKeys` will be `["MyKey1"]`

**P.S:** A good practice is to use upper cases for types' names. So I would suggest to changes your `typealias` to `DictString`.